# Dispatching a Laravel job in scheduler, pre-5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, laravel-5.4

I'm used to Laravel 5.5+ where you can call `$schedule->job(new ExampleJob);` to fire jobs, which is not available in 5.4. I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    dispatch(new AppointmentReminder);
})->dailyAt('08:00');
```

but the job is not firing. I've verified that this is being called at the correct time. I'm guessing the `dispatch()` method is not available in `App\Console\Kernal.php`? Does anyone know of the official way of dispatching jobs in 5.4's scheduler? This is a legacy code base and all of the jobs are inline in the `Kernal.php` which is a total mess. Not to mention this is a rather involved job.

I did try `use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;`/`use DispatchesJobs;` and then `$this->dispatch(new AppointmentReminder());` in `Kernal.php`, but that did not seem to do the trick either. Also, `(new AppointmentReminder())->dispatch();` does not work. Thanks!

Comment: do you have this, in your crontab?

* * * * * php /path/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: It's running. I through a Log::info(); in the callback and one in the Job itself. The scheduler log fires, but I've yet to get to the job itself.

Comment: Also, I can manually fire the job via tinker, so that seems fine. Regardless, having a log in the handle() method would fire even if there was some logic issue beyond that. So my issue really seems to be dispatching the job from the scheduler.

Comment: My current (non-ideal) workaround:$schedule->call(function () {
            $appointmentReminder = new AppointmentReminder();
            $appointmentReminder->handle();
        })->dailyAt('08:00');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new console command:

```
php artisan make:command CommandName
```

add it to App\Console\Kernal.php:

```
protected $commands = [
Commands\CommandName::class,      
];
```

and make you schedual call it:

```
$schedule->command('CommandName')->dailyAt('08:00');
```

and inside your command in the "handle" function, dispatch the job.